# implementing Android AR with UVC / External camera (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm working on an AR project (Unity) and I want to use an external camera instead of my Android's original one. I saw that Vuforia has such a feature - but claims that ny using that, Ground Plane detection wouldn't work at all and ModelTargets performances taking a hit.
I also saw EasyAR has CustomCamera and Camera2 lib in ARCore.
Question is: What's the best way to approach this? has anyone experienced using an external camera? and with what AR solution? (ARFoundation / Vuforia / EasyAR...).
2nd Question: What should I look for when buying said UVC? Any examples for one?
Also I'd like to hear about experiences with AR solutions regardless of the external camera thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is unlikely to work with an external camera.

A key part of AR is having a precise calibration of the camera's optics. Without that, it's not possible to accurately analyze the world to draw new objects in it or other AR effects.

A UVC webcam doesn't come with any such calibration information. So it would have to be calibrated somehow, and the calibration information given to Unity's AR engine. I don't know if that's possible with Unity in some way.

Note that not that all internal camera devices on Android are calibrated enough for AR either, but the ARCore team is certifying devices that have sufficient calibration in place.